# Loop for forecasting values on a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a date column and 100 columns with values for different locations, which should be forecasted. I used `tbats()` and `forecast()`, from package `forecast`, to do the forecasting, which worked perfectly for the first column (which I extracted from the data frame). 
But now I want to run a loop on all the columns. In this loop, the fit model (`tbats()`) should be calculated for every column, and then with `forecast` the future values for each column (which are all independent) should be computed (for 365 days).

I can't figure out the loop, I tried separate things like:

```
for(i in names(test)) df <- data.frame(forecast(tbats(ts(test[i],frequency=365)),h=365))
```

or

```
# wrote a function and tried to use lapply:
func <- function(x){ 
  ts1 <- ts(x,frequency=365) 
  tbats(ts1)
  forecast(ts1,h=365)
} 
lapply(data,func)
```

I would like to have a data frame, which looks exactly like the one in my original dataset, but with the predicted values for future dates. So columns: Date, location_1, location_2, ....

How can I do such a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the function `apply()` which will act on all rows in a data frame. You might need to remove the first column with the date:

```
apply(df[,-1], 2, function (x) forecast(tbats(ts(x,frequency=365)), h=365))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the `mean` value column, try:

```
 lst1 <- lapply(dat[,-1], function(x) forecast(tbats(ts(x, frequency=365)), h=365))
 resM <- do.call(data.frame, do.call(rbind, lst1)[,"mean"])
 dim(resM)
 #[1] 365   3
 head(resM,2)
 #  location_1 location_2 location_3
 #1 -0.01576029   2.742711   25.04357
 #2 -0.02351485   2.722169   25.04353
```

Or if you need `fitted values`

```
 resF <- do.call(data.frame,do.call(rbind, lst1)[,"fitted"])
 dim(resF)
 #[1] 455   3

 resF1 <- cbind(Date=dat[,1], resF)
 resF1[,-1] <- lapply(resF1[,-1], as.numeric)
 str(resF1)
 #'data.frame': 455 obs. of  4 variables:
 #$ Date      : Date, format: "2010-10-24" "2010-10-25" ...
 #$ location_1: num  0.444 0.337 0.333 0.284 0.225 ...
 #$ location_2: num  3.02 3.01 3.04 3.05 3.08 ...
 #$ location_3: num  25 25 25 25 25 ...
```

#### data

```
 set.seed(42)
 dat <- data.frame(Date=seq(as.Date("2010-10-24"), length.out=455, by=1),
      location_1=rnorm(455), location_2=rnorm(455, 3, 15), location_3=rnorm(455, 25))
```